# Is there a possibility that pipeline.fireChannelActive() is executed twice when executing ServerBootstrap.bind()?

Tags: netty

All the following code is from Netty4.0.31.Final. The `ServerBootstrap`'s channel is `NioServerSocketChannel`.

The main logic of `ServerBootstrap.bind(int)` is in `AbstractBootstrap.doBind(SocketAddress)`:

```
private ChannelFuture doBind(final SocketAddress localAddress) {
        final ChannelFuture regFuture = initAndRegister();
        ...
        if (regFuture.isDone()) {
            ...
            doBind0(regFuture, channel, localAddress, promise);
            ...
        } else {
            regFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                    ...
                    doBind0(regFuture, channel, localAddress, promise);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

The code in `initAndRegister()` finally goes into `AbstractUnsafe.register0(ChannelPromise promise)`:

```
private void register0(ChannelPromise promise) {
        try {
            ...
            boolean firstRegistration = neverRegistered;
            doRegister();
            ...
            if (firstRegistration && isActive()) {
                pipeline.fireChannelActive();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            ...
        }
 }
```

As you can see, `pipeline.fireChannelActive()` may be executed here.

Let's back to `AbstractBootstrap.doBind(SocketAddress)`,in `doBind0(regFuture, channel, localAddress, promise)` the code finally goes into `AbstractUnsafe.bind(SocketAddress,ChannelPromise)`:

```
public final void bind(final SocketAddress localAddress, final ChannelPromise promise) {
        ...
        boolean wasActive = isActive();
        try {
            doBind(localAddress);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            ...
        }

        if (!wasActive && isActive()) {
            invokeLater(new OneTimeTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pipeline.fireChannelActive();
                }
            });
        }
        ...
    }
```

As you can see, `pipeline.fireChannelActive()` may also be executed here.

So, is there a possibility that `pipeline.fireChannelActive()` is executed twice when creating and binding one `NioServerSocketChannel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless `isActive` can flip flop from true to false to true again in the flow you pointed out. I think it can only go active once, so false -> true -> false

Relevant code from your post:

```
boolean firstRegistration = neverRegistered;
...
if (firstRegistration && isActive()) {
    pipeline.fireChannelActive();  // isActive must be TRUE
}
...
boolean wasActive = isActive();
...
// If fireChannelActive was fired, then wasActive would be true, 
// preventing it from firing again
if (!wasActive && isActive()) {  
    invokeLater(new OneTimeTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pipeline.fireChannelActive();
```

Comment: Yes, I know the answer is no now. But the key point (or another explanation) is that `AbstractUnsafe.register0(ChannelPromise promise)` and `AbstractUnsafe.bind(SocketAddress,ChannelPromise)` are both executed by the EventLoop. `AbstractUnsafe.register0(ChannelPromise promise)` is executed before `AbstractUnsafe.bind(SocketAddress,ChannelPromise)`, so `isActive()` will return false in `AbstractUnsafe.register0(ChannelPromise promise)`.